# display the first N words from database field in DataList

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, datalist

I need to get first n words from database and display them in the DataList. I'm using LINQ to SQL.
I Have searched a lot but can't find a way doing this, I'm trying make a list of article with 300 character of them and a Read More link,I will be able to handle the read more button and showing article page but I stuck in showing limited words in articles list. I'm using DataList because I want to simply display other fields in
it.

I can make array of my table column an i have number of rows:

```
var arc = (from a in data.Articles select a).Count();
var ar = (from a in data.Articles select a.ArticleText).ToArray();
var article = ar;
```

and this is how I can extract 5 words from a string:

```
string firstWords = Regex.Match(testString, @"^(\w+\b.*?){5}").ToString();
```

I can't make this things work together

is it possible to use eval expression for arrays?

update: I did a typo mistake in my question wrote gridview instead of datalist.

update2: I could make a array of limited words and bind it to datalist by puting <%#Container.DataItem %> in datalist but I can't use other datasources like linqdatasource to use eval to showing other data fields  because I used datalist1.DataSource = ar.

code:

```
string[] limitedarticle;
limitedarticle = new string[arc];

for (int i = 0; i < arc; i++)
 {

   limitedarticle[i] = Regex.Match(article[i], @"^(\w+\b.*?){5}").ToString();


 }
datalist1.DataSource = ar ;
datalist1.DataBind();
```

I appreciate any guidance and help

Answer (score 1):

You can get `n` rows with this:

```
var arc = (from a in data.Articles select a).Take(5);
```

That would give you `5` rows. You could then actually take that result and data-bind it to the `GridView`.

To limit the number of words from `ArticleText`, do this:

```
var ar = (from a in data.Articles select a.ArticleText.Take(50));
```

Comment: but how could I limit the number of words displaying from ArticleText